# Why this question was down-voted?

Tags: discussion, questions

**[Is there any indication that Apple/iCloud will offer a “photo collection hosting” service, comparable to Picasa Web Albums?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/45386/128)**

Why this question was down voted two times? I think it is a legitimate question! 
Or is it a bad question, because actually no real answer exists (because nobody know if Apple provides a photo hosting in the future again)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a open-ended question, not based on an actual problem.
Answers will rather reflect a debate than come to conclusions.
This is not the aim of the stackexchange network and such questions do not fit the Q&A format.

Like the [FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) says,

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about ...."., then you should not be
>   asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to
>   explain .... to me”, then you are probably OK.

Answer (score 3):

The increase in questions of lower quality brought about by the iPad promotion has everone's shields up so the down voting may be more rigorous than it was previously.

You nailed the reason for the down votes of this one—*there is no objective answer*. Matt's response and the FAQ should fill in the blanks but a *litmus test* that I sometimes like to apply is that on **Ask Different** we want you to tell us what you *know*, not what you *think*.

Granted this test isn't black and white. Some questions do leave room for opinion, and sometimes there are different *correct* (or at least *workable*)solutions that might be subject to valid debate. However, the more subjective (or worse still, *speculative*) a resulting answer is likely to be, the less likely the question will meet the test for **quality**.